# Обратный метод доступа конфликтует с Django

Tags: python, django

В модели у меня есть такая ошибка:

```
apps.Company.owner: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Company.owner' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Company.owner'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Company.owner' or 'Company.owner'.
main.Company.owner: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Company.owner' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Company.owner'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Company.owner' or 'Company.owner'.
```

Вот код модели:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)


def create_folder(**kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    print(instance.id)
    os.mkdir(f"media/company_{instance.id}")


def delete_folder(**kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    print(instance.id)
    full_patch_folder = f"media/company_{instance.id}"
    if os.path.isdir(full_patch_folder):
        shutil.rmtree(full_patch_folder)


post_save.connect(create_folder, sender=Company)
post_delete.connect(delete_folder, sender=Company)


class Folder(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    unique_folder_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    full_path = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    parent_folder = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Parent Folder", blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, verbose_name="Company", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    share = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Share folder", null=True, default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "(id.%s) - %s - %s - %s - %s" % (self.id, self.name, self.unique_folder_name,  self.share, self.company)
```

я добавлял `related_name='Company.company'` и `'User.user'` в каждый метод, но не работает. Помогите решить. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

У вас 2 приложения, в обоих модель `Company` и в обеих связь с пользователем. Укажите для одной или для обеих корректный `related_name`.
Корректный `related_name` состоит из латинских символов, цифр и знака подчеркивания, если кратко. `related_name` по отношению к оной модели должны быть уникальны.

Т.е.

```
#apps

class Company(...):
    owner = models.ForeighnKey(..., related_name='apps_companies')


#main

class Company(...):
    owner = models.ForeighnKey(..., related_name='main_companies')
```

Comment: А вообще, гуглится и читается в документации

Comment: а вообщем не помогло, все сам прочитал, нужно было + добавить и все

Comment: `related_name="+"` это другой способ, но он скорее добавит сложностей при работе с объектами в обратном порядке